# Raspberry Pi 4 is unable to ping each other

Tags: pi-4

I am new at this and has been trying for a week. So my project needs me to connect 2 rpi-4 wirelessly while also being connected to the computers via wireless and wired. so in my RPI-1 I set it up changing my WLAN0 to an access point where I will be able to use my computer to connect it via wifi. However, this disable my wifi for RPI-1. For RPI-2 I have set up a new access point called AP0 where I can connect my second computer to RPI-2 while able to use the WLAN0 for wifi to connect to RPI-1. However, my problem is that I am able to ping from RPI-2 to RPI-1, but unable to ping from RPI-1 to RPI-2. Is there a way to ping both ways as I need to communicate both way. Thank you

edited:
for RPI-1, I made WLAN0 to be a WIFI Access Point by giving it a static IP of 192.168.0.1 changing the "/etc/dhcpcd.conf"

```
interface wlan0  
static ip_address=192.168.0.1/24  
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

then proceed to edit "/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"

```
interface=wlan0  
ssid=mySSID  
hw_mode=g  
channel=7  
macaddr_acl=0  
auth_algs=1  
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0  
wpa=2  
wpa_passphrase=passw0rd  
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK  
wpa_pairwise=TKIP  
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

edit the file, “/etc/default/hostapd”

```
DAEMON_CONF=”/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf”
```

edit the file "/etc/dnsmasq.conf"

```
interface=wlan0
 dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.150,255.255.255.0,24h
```

then i disable the hostapd and enable it back.
this allow me to use WLAN0 to be a wireless hotspot.

for RPI-2
I did the same as RPI-1 but instead of naming it WLAN0, i used ap0, so i can use WLAN0 for wifi where i can connect to RPI-1
edit "/etc/dhcpcd.conf"

```
interface ap0
static ip_address=192.168.0.2/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

then proceed to edit "/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"

```
interface=ap0
ssid=mySSID2
hw_mode=g
channel=7
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=passw0rd
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

edit the file, “/etc/default/hostapd”

```
DAEMON_CONF=”/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf”
```

edit the file "/etc/dnsmasq.conf"

```
interface=ap0
 dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.150,255.255.255.0,24h
```

after editing all this, i create an ap0.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Create ap0 interface
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add ap0 type __ap
ExecStartPost=/sbin/ifconfig ap0 up
ExecStop=/sbin/iw dev ap0 del

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my RPI-1 ifconfig
[image: ifconfig rpi-1]

my RPI-2 ifconfig[image: ifconfig rpi-2]

ping from rpi-1 to rpi-2
[image: ping from rpi-1 to rpi-2]

ping from rpi-2 to rpi-1[image: ping from rpi-2 to rpi-1]

Comment: This is incomprehensible. Explain what you have actually done and list diagnostics.

Comment: @Milliways Hi, sorry for not adding my configuration. I have edited my post on the configurations and i am unsure on the diagnostics on how i can fix. Thank you

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post text. What OS? You appear to have attempted to create 2 Access Points WHY? You can not expect to run 2 networks on the same subnet which is unlikely to be successful. This is OK if that is what you want but you should use different subnets and you also seem to want one (or both) to also act as a client

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the routing tables on both Raspberry Pis (route -n). Check if there is a route between the two subnets. Also check the configurations of both access points. Make sure that they are set up correctly. Make sure they are not conflicting with each other.

Comment: RPI-1  
`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0         0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0         U    303    0        0 wlan0`
RPI-2  
`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 ap0`
my IP is not conflicting each other

Comment: OK. Please check if the wireless interfaces on both Raspberry Pis are configured properly and are up (ifconfig or ip link show).

Comment: using ip link show, it shows that both WLAN0 is up and for RPI-2 where there AP0, it is also up. I can connect RPI-2 to RPI-1 using wifi and can ping one way but not 2 way